# MS Analysis Services - Calculated measure in measure group

Tags: ssas, measure

In my cube I have defined a calculated measure as the sum of two other measures. How can I make this measure show up in one of my measure groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your cube script where the calculated measure is defined, like so:

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Calculated Measure]
 AS ([Measures].[Measure 1] / [Measures].[Measure 2]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "Percent", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Measure 1], [Measure 2] }, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  **DISPLAY_FOLDER = '\Custom Folder'** , **ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Custom Measure Group'**;

The properties relevant to your question are in bold.